# El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. [Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070002]

Tags: c#

Tengo un programa que funcionaba perfectamente hasta que apareció este error mientras se ejecutaba el .exe (Release) en otro ordenador donde no esta instalado el Visual Studio.

> Error: ModuleMain getFileVersion El sistema no puede encontrar el
>   archivo especificado. [Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070002]

No puedo subir el código por la propiedad intelectual, pero principalmente lo que hace es ejecutar una Query a una Base de Datos cada "X" minutos (controlados por un `Timer`).

Utilizo Visual Studio 2015 en Windwos 10 y la aplicación es un Windows Form Application (C#)

Comment: Comprueba que version de .net framework usa tu aplicación, y asegurate de que esté presente en la máquina de destino

Comment: esto sucede cuando ejecutas desde el VS o cuando llevas la aplicacion a la pc del usuario ? lo pregunto porque quizas no llevaste el archivo `.config` de donde obtiene el connection string

Comment: No dices si solo llevaste el aplicativo en bruto o creaste un instalador, si no lo has hecho crea primero un instalador, hay veces que no se lleva todo lo necesario para que el aplicativo funcione en otro equipo. La base de datos es sql, oracle, mysql? lo pregunto por que hay veces en los que se debe instalar los clientes necesarios en los equipos. Saludos.-

Comment: Pikoh - Ok, lo haré

Comment: CL - Soy nuevo creando programas en C#, lo que he hecho es ejecutarlo en Release, copiarlo y llevarmelo al otro pc. La BBDD es oracle

Comment: Leandro Tuttini - Funcionaba perfectamente hasta que de pronto, sucedió, llevaba 3 días activo sin ningún problema